# Wavelet cross-correlation in Matlab interpretation

Tags: matlab, cross-correlation

I am trying to determine the lag between two time series using the wavelet cross correlation for lead-lag analysis in Matlab but have some trouble interpreting the results.  Code used is

```
[xc,lags] = xcorr(x,y);
[~,I] = max(abs(xc));
figure
stem(lags,xc,'filled')
legend(sprintf('Maximum at lag %d',lags(I)))
title('Cross-Correlation Sequence for x and y')
```

Result shows a maximum at lag of -5, my question is does this mean that x lags y by 5 years or does y lag x by 5 years? Any help on this would be appreciated, thanks.

A look at the results produced using this code is shown below:

[image]

Comment: There is no image.  Please attach it with your post.

Comment: If you are unsure which way around it is, an easy way to tell is by making artificial time series `x` and `y` with a *known* relationship, and see what comes out.

Comment: Some [documentation on the web](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/xcorr.html) indicates that when you do `xcorr(earlier,later)` the peak occurs at a negative lag. So in your example I think `x` leads `y` rather than vice versa.

Comment: @rayryeng, sorry I have added the link did not realize I could not embed and image as yet.

Comment: Those negative `xcorr` values in your plot look a bit strange. Is one of your time series negated as well as leading/lagged?

Comment: The time series are just lead/lag, its precipitation and temperature.